# Dialob Box not showing when previewing CodeName One "hello world" project?

Tags: codenameone

Just starting with CodeName One and the hello world project with the GUI builder.
I added an action listener (through the GUI Builder) and a line inside it to show up a dialog box:

```
protected void onMain_ButtonAction(Component c, ActionEvent event) {
    Dialog.show("Hello", "Hi there!", "OK", null);
    }
```

Then I click on "Simulate Device", the phone does show up and I can click the button but no Dialog pops up? Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally this should work, but is it possible you don't have an override annotation there?

Did you rename the form or do you have another button with the same name?

I suggest checking out [this tutorial](http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---handle-eventsnavigation-in-the-gui-builder--populate-the-form-from-code.html).